# Does Rsync use internet data to transfer files remotely?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, rsync, sshd

I have learned to use `rsync` yesterday. I use it to push files to my Android device ([Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page)) and I even pull files from my Android device (Termux).

I use this command to *push*:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 8022' -vaP <source> <username>@<ipaddresss>:/sdcard/rsync
```

And I use this command to *pull*:

```
rsync -e 'ssh -p 8022' -vaP <username>@<ipaddresss>:/sdcard/rsync/* /home/me/rsync/
```

And I noticed that the transfer rate of files are more than 16000Kbps, which is way faster than my internet connection (which is slower than 250Kbps).

So, here's my question: doesn't `rsync` use internet data to transfer files remotely?

> **Note:** Both my laptop and smartphone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. :)

Comment: If your phone is connected to your private wireless network (e.g. at home), no data need to go out on the public Internet. Speeds would therefore not be limited to whatever speed cap you have on your Internet connection, as the data does not pass out of your local network. I'm not posting this as an answer as you have said nothing about what manner of network the phone is connected to.

Comment: Both my laptop and smartphone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your phone is connected to the same local network as you laptop and since you presumably use the local addresses of the devices on that local network (i.e. not any public addresses or names), no data will ever be transferred through your Internet provider's router.  It's on that router that your bandwidth is limited.  This means that `rsync` will be able to use the full bandwidth of your local network.

If you move your phone outside of your local network and connect to your laptop with some public IP or name, then you will be restricted by your service provider's limits (and possibly by congestions etc. on intermediate networks).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, Kusalananda. :)